# How to solve the error in update MS Access Database

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong in the following code.
It gives a syntax error.

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET Password=? WHERE User_Name=?"
cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pwn)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", un)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Password Updated Successfully")
```

Comment: Can you check my answer

Comment: Yes sir its working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PASSWORD is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), change your code to

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET [Password]=? WHERE User_Name=?"
cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pwn)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", un)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Password Updated Successfully")
```

BY the way, if you are still able to do so, I suggest to change this column to a non reserved word, otherwise you have this problem everytime

Answer (score 0):

Password is a reserverd key so use `[Password]`

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET [Password]=? WHERE User_Name=?"
//str = "UPDATE Users SET [Password]=@Password WHERE User_Name=@User_Name"

cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pwn)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", un)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Password Updated Successfully")
```

[reserved Keywords](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266)

Comment: @S.Manjunathan I have answered your question as first.But you are accepting anotherone answer as useful